# Why does VS 2017 generate GetHashCode without an unchecked block

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gethashcode

I recently discovered that Visual Studio 2017 can auto-generate overrides for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but I was wondering why the `GetHashCode` implementation is not in an [unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) block?

I made a simple class with two public string properties Foo and Bar, and the generated `GetHashCode` implementation is shown below.

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var hashCode = -504981047;
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Foo);
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Bar);
    return hashCode;
}
```

I was under the impression the unchecked for `GetHashCode` implementations was important because it was very likely to overflow, and we don't want any overflow exceptions because it's fine if it wraps around.

Comment: It should be, but sadly C# project templates do not turn on overflow checking so they didn't consider it.

Comment: @HansPassant your comment lead to check how to turn on overflow checking for a C# project, and if overflow checking is turned on for the project, then the override of GetHashCode is put in an unchecked block.

Comment: That's pretty clever.  Bummer if you decide to turn it on afterwards though.

Comment: @HansPassant it would have been better if it was always in an unchecked block just for that scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default C# projects do not check for overflow and underflow.

Right click on the project, Select `Properties`, On the `Build` Tab at the bottom select `Advanced...`, Check the box labeled `Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow`

Now the default behavior is to throw `System.OverflowException` if there is ever an overflow not in an explicit `unchecked` block.

If you auto-generate overrides for `Equals` and `GetHashCode` with overflow checking turned on for the project, then the unchecked block is there as expected

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = -504981047;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Foo);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Bar);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently my understanding of no checks vs unchecked vs checked was flawed. It was simple enough to write some simple tests to see overflow behavior in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gmpl5G).

The quick summary is this:

**If running with no explicit checks**

- If the compiler can easily and statically determine that code will overflow, there will be a compile error.
- If there is an overflow at runtime there will *not* be any overflow exceptions thrown.

**If running explicitly unchecked**

- The compiler will allow code that will obviously overflow
- No runtime overflow exceptions will be thrown

**If running explicitly checked**

- If the compiler can easily and statically determine that code will overflow, there will be a compile error.
- If there is an overflow at runtime a `System.OverflowException` will be thrown.

So... I guess the lesson from all of this is if you have some calculations that may overflow, and you care about overflow, it is very important to put that inside of a `checked` block. If you have code that may overflow, and you don't care about overflow, apparently you can skip the unchecked block (unless your code will obviously overflow from a static analysis point of view).

The code from the fiddle is copied here as well for posterity.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int test = 0;

        //obscured enough that the compiler doesn't "know" that the line will produce an overflow
        //Does not run explicitly as checked, so no runtime OverflowException is thrown
        test = rand.Next(Int32.MaxValue-2, Int32.MaxValue) + 10;

        //simple enough that the compiler "knows" that the line will produce an overflow
        //Compilation error (line 16, col 10): The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode
        //test = Int32.MaxValue + 1;

        //Explicitly running as unchecked. Compiler allows line that is "known" to overflow.
        unchecked
        {
            test = Int32.MaxValue + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        //Explicitly running as unchecked. Still no runtime OverflowException
        unchecked
        {
            test = test - 10;   
        }

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        //Explicitly running as checked. System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
        checked
        {
            test = test + 10;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```